# Invalid character found in string argument 'DECFLOAT'

Tags: sql, db2

I seem to be having a problem using with a filed when used in a case statement. For example when I try:

```
select a.*,
case when value > 0 then non_zero
     else value
from mytable a
```

where I get:

```
Invalid character found in string argument of the function 'DECFLOAT'
```

usually I come across this type of error by forgetting to cast the field as decimal, but this makes no difference. However if I try:

```
select * from mytable where value > 0
```

then this runs fine.

So why will my criteria not work within the case statement?

Comment: what is datatype of `non_zero` and `value` columns?

Comment: I think non_zero and value has different type and the query fails bacause of that.

Comment: hi - they are both of type decimal

Comment: I think you should show your actual statement, along with the table definitions, rather than an invalid "example".

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot your "end case". Try this:

```
select a.*,
case 
  when value > 0 then non_zero
  else value
end case
from a
```

Comment: The `case` after the `end` is unnecessary, and will be interpreted as what you wish to call the result column.